# why is this not right output in this pattern?

Tags: php, singleton

```
class person {
private static $_instance = null ;
private $name,
        $age ;

private function __construct($name,$age) {
            $this->name = $name ;
             $this->age = $age ;  
          } 

public static function instance () {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {

        self::$_instance = new person () ;
    } 

    return self::$_instance ;
}

public function tellName($name,$age) {
    echo $this->name." age is".$this->age ;
}
}


  $c = person::instance('ram',23) ;
  $c->tellName() ;
  var_dump($c) ; 



  $d = person::instance('shyam',23) ;
  $d->tellName() ;
  var_dump($d) ;
```

output is not show name & age .
In singleton pattern how to set value in private variable.like old method we call new class($a,$b) but i this we can write class::instance($a,$b) set construct function . how can i set new object for tellName function . still give null value .

Comment: You're echoing `$this->name` which is a null, and `$this->age` which is a null

Comment: If you want to use the class properties, then you need to assign values to them.... the arguments that you pass to the method aren't assigned to properties automagically

Comment: And don't make your constructor private.

Comment: @Daan - private constructor for singleton pattern is correct.... though why OP is using a singleton here, I don't know

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes it works, but I think it's a bad habit to make constructors private even in singleton classes.

Comment: If they're not private in a singleton, then how can you enforce the singleton?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, `public` will also work just fine. Not a fan of singleton classes anyway.

Comment: The difficulty with a public constructor and a singleton is that userland code can do `$x = new person(); $y = new person();` and you now have 2 instances of the supposed singleton

Comment: @MarkBaker but in var_dump  only one instance show but values are null

Comment: @gaurav Of course they're null, because you're never assigning them: assign the `$name` and `$age` arguments that you're passing to the `tellname()` method to `$this->name` and `$this->age` respectively

Comment: @MarkBaker still not working

Comment: [This is what you have to do](https://3v4l.org/HUZFc)

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks Sir

Comment: @MarkBaker Understood you can indeed create 2 instances which is not the intention of a singleton. As I said not a fan of singleton classes.